# yarn workspaces and lerna cause Invalid Hook call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, lerna, yarn-workspaces

I think this is a **duplicate React problem**

**Current behavior :**
In the `container` project, it works fine when I route to `sub-app/foo`. But when I route to `sub-app` I get the following error :

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
 You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
 You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
 You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

Notice: `sub-app/foo` will get a class component. `sub-app` will get a React hooks component

**Expected behavior**: The result I expect is that the `subApp` code will work fine in the `container`

The Project Structure:

```
/mono-repo
  packages
  - container
  - subApp
```

```js
// /packages/container/src/App.js
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import About from './About';
import Header from './Header';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable'

const Logo = () => {
  return <div>LOGO</div>
}

const loadableComponent = (loader) => {
  return Loadable({
    loader: () =>
      loader().then(
        (res) => {
          return res
        },
        (e) => () => {
          console.log(e)
        }
      ),
    loading() {
      return (
        <div>loading</div>
      )
    }
  })
}

const loadSubApp = (subAppInfo) => {
  const { name, host } = subAppInfo
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
    fetch(`${host}/${name}/asset-manifest.json`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(manifest => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = `${host}${manifest.files['main.js']}`;
        const timeout = setTimeout(()=>{
          console.error(`MicroApp ${name} timeout`);
          reject(new Error(`MicroApp ${name} timeout`));
        },20000)
        script.onload = () => {
          clearTimeout(timeout)
          const app = window[name]
          console.log({app, name})
          console.log(`MicroApp ${name} loaded success`);
          resolve(app)
        }
        script.onerror = (e) => {
          clearTimeout(timeout);
          console.error(`MicroApp ${name} loaded error`, e);
          reject(e)
        }
        document.body.appendChild(script);
      })
  })
}

const subLoader = (name) => async () => {
  const App = await loadSubApp({ name: 'subApp', host: process.env.REACT_APP_SUBAPP_HOST })
  console.log({App, window})
  return App[name]
}



const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <React.Fragment>
        <Logo />
        <ul>
          <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
          <Link to="/header">header</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
          <Link to="/sub-app">subApp</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
          <Link to="/sub-app/foo">subApp foo</Link>
          </li>
          
        </ul>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={About} />
          <Route exact path="/header" render={() => <Header /> }/>
          <Route exact path="/sub-app/foo" render={()=> {
            const RenderSubApp = loadableComponent(subLoader('Foo'))
            return <RenderSubApp />
          }}/>
          <Route exact path="/sub-app" render={()=> {
            const RenderSubApp = loadableComponent(subLoader('Count'))
            return <RenderSubApp />
          }}/>
        </Switch>
      </React.Fragment>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

```js
// /packages/subApp/config-overrides.js
const {
  override,
  // addWebpackAlias
} = require("customize-cra");
// const path = require("path");

const dropConsole = () => {
  return (config) => {

    if (config.optimization.minimizer) {
      config.optimization.minimizer.forEach((minimizer) => {
        if (minimizer.constructor.name === "TerserPlugin") {
          minimizer.options.terserOptions.compress.drop_console = true;
        }
      });
    }
    return config;
  };
};

const optBuild= () => config => {
  config.optimization.runtimeChunk = false;
  config.optimization.splitChunks = {
    cacheGroups: {
      default: false,
    },
  }; 
  return config
}

const disableSourceMap = () => (config) => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    config.devtool = false;
  }
  return config;
};

const customizeCraOverride = override(
  disableSourceMap(),
  dropConsole(),
  optBuild(),
  // addWebpackAlias({
  //   'react': path.resolve(__dirname, '../container/node_modules/react'),
  //   'react-dom': path.resolve(__dirname, '../container/node_modules/react-dom')
  // })
);

const webpack = (config, env) => {
  const webpackConfig = customizeCraOverride(config, env);

  return {
    ...webpackConfig,
    output: {
      ...webpackConfig.output,
      library: "subApp",
      libraryTarget: 'window',
    },
    // externals: {
    //   'react': 'react',
    //   'react-dom': 'react-dom'
    // },
  };
};

module.exports = {
  webpack,
};
```

The project link [bug-demo](https://github.com/LiuL0703/bug-demo)

those solution doesn't work for me

- https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html
- https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991
- https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15315
- [Solve having more than one copy of React in the same app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66488492/solve-having-more-than-one-copy-of-react-in-the-same-app)
- [Yarn Workspaces and Invalid Hook call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61263658/yarn-workspaces-and-invalid-hook-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved this problem.

```
// /packages/subApp/config-overrides.js

 ...

const webpack = (config, env) => {
  const webpackConfig = customizeCraOverride(config, env);

  return {
    ...webpackConfig,
    output: {
      ...webpackConfig.output,
      library: "subApp",
      libraryTarget: 'window',
    },
    externals: {
       'react': 'React',
       'react-dom': 'ReactDOM'
    },
  };
};
module.exports = {
  webpack
};
```

```
// packages/container/src/index.js

...

export {
  React,
  ReactDOM
}
```

```
// packages/container/config-overrides.js

  ...

const webpack = (config, env) => {
  const webpackConfig = customizeCraOverride(config, env);
  return {
    ...webpackConfig,
    output: {
      ...webpackConfig.output,
      libraryTarget: 'umd',
    },
  }
};
module.exports = {
  webpack
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this completely solves your problem but the error goes away and the routes work correctly. Nothing loads, I am pretty sure that I don't have the correct environment variables. But, basically you just had some faulty router code in your `/packages/container/src/App.js` file. I cloned the repository and this is what I changed it to:

```
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={About} />
      <Route exact path="/header" render={() => <Header /> }/>
      <Route exact path="/sub-app" render={()=> {
        const RenderSubApp = loadableComponent(subLoader('Count'))
        return <RenderSubApp />
      }}>
        <Route exact path="/foo" render={()=> {
          const RenderSubApp = loadableComponent(subLoader('Foo'))
          return <RenderSubApp />
        }}/>
      </Route>
    </Switch>
```

Notice how the `/foo` route becomes a child of the `/sub-app` route. Although the error is gone React still shows a warning message: `Warning: You should not use <Route render> and <Route children> in the same route; <Route render> will be ignored`. I am not exactly sure how lerna works, but there might be some workaround for this.

Check out [this section](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#defining-routes) of the react-router docs.

Comment: I will keep looking into this to see if I can find more.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this is not the answer I was looking for.Obviously this is a duplicate react problem. `/sub-app/foo` is just a control experiment for `sub-app`.I'm trying to prove that React Hooks don't work properly in `container`.